# How to Implement stack by function pointer and how to use it

Tags: c, stack, function-pointers

I know that struct in c only consist of member are variables but don't have any declaration functions. Is that right? 
 
Do we use function pointer instead of function in a struct?

for example:
+ With c++ having function as member of class

```
class stack{
  int[10] data;
  int top;

public:                 
  void init();          
  bool isEmpty();           
  bool isFull();            
  void push(int ivalue);
  int pop();
}
```

+ with C, can't do that.

```
    struct stack(
    int[10] data;
    int top;

    void int();     // wrong here
    ....
)
```

so Do we implement stack with function pointer? 
Please give me an example and how to use it?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question is not very clear or at the very least not constructed well. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I already edited it and note that the next times.

Comment: I put on my mind reading cap and interpreted your question as, "how can I emulate classes in C?"  Refer to this [tutorial](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~selfpace/studyguide/9C.sg/Output/ADTs.in.C.html) on implementing abstract data types in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, function members cannot be declared in C structs (only in C++). The convention is to pass the struct pointer as the first argument in the functions when doing object oriented programming.  Also, C++ really does the same thing, the "this" pointer is passed as the first argument, it is just hidden.

```
struct stack{
  int[10] data;
  int top;
};

void stack_init(struct stack* stack);          
int stack_isEmpty(struct stack* stack);           
int stack_isFull(struct stack* stack);            
void stack_push(struct stack* stack, int ivalue);
int stack_pop(struct stack* stack);
```

This part below may be more than what you are asking for but if you want the functions to be more "dynamic", you can put function pointers in the struct to make them "changeable", i.e. to simulate the virtual keyword in c++.

```
struct stack{
    int[10] data;
    int top;
    int (*isEmpty)(struct stack* stack);           
    int (*isFull)(struct stack* stack);            
    void (*push)(struct stack* stack, int ivalue);
    int (*pop)(struct stack* stack);
};

int stack_isEmpty1(struct stack* stack);           
int stack_isFull1(struct stack* stack);            
void stack_push1(struct stack* stack, int ivalue);
int stack_pop1(struct stack* stack);

void stack_init1(struct stack* stack)
{
    stack->isEmpty = &stack_isEmpty1;
    stack->isFull = &stack_isFull1;
    stack->push = &stack_push1;
    stack->pop = &stack_pop1;
    ...
}

int stack_isEmpty2(struct stack* stack);           
int stack_isFull2(struct stack* stack);            
void stack_push2(struct stack* stack, int ivalue);
int stack_pop2(struct stack* stack);

void stack_init2(struct stack* stack)
{
    stack->isEmpty = &stack_isEmpty2;
    stack->isFull = &stack_isFull2;
    stack->push = &stack_push2;
    stack->pop = &stack_pop2;
    ...
}
```

So now if you have 2 stack objects, initialized with stack_init1 and stack_init2 respectfully, they each will call their own sets of functions. Example:

```
struct stack* a, b;
stack_init1(a);
stack_init2(b);

/* This will call stack_isEmpty1*/
a->isEmpty(a);

/* This will call stack_isEmpty2*/
b->isEmpty(b);
```